# referencing a jsp from another

Tags: html, jsp, href

I am working with `Java servlets`, and I am new to it.
I was trying to write a `jsp page` wherein I will have a menu ( a list of links ).

In `index.jsp` I have the following `code:`

```
 <ul>
       <li> <a href="http://www.google.co.za">Home<a/> </li>
       <li> <a href="login.jsp">login here<a/> </li>
 </ul>
```

but when I click on the first link it works, but crushed when I click on the second link. `login.jsp` exists within the same `dir` as 'index.jsp'

how can I get `login.jsp` to work as well?

Comment: What URL are you hitting ?

Comment: `/WEB-INF/classes/jsp/login.jsp` is the jsp i wanna open.. this login.jsp is in the same folder `jsp` as `index.jsp`

Comment: *You cannot access jsp under WEB-INF. It is not a standard J2EE Spec. The container only looks for class-files in WEB-INF and if you ask for jsp in this directory, it will return an error 404.* btw , when you click on that link , what URL the shows up in browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. My JSP files were within `WEB-INF`. Just found out that what is in `` `WEB-INF `` is private and cannot be accessed dirrectly. So I put them on the root folder of the project ( in parallel to `WEB-INF` )

Answer (score 0):

Put your login.jsp in /WEB-INF folder and then try.Do not put it under anything else